# What is max_messages proper value for running message queue using cron job?

Tags: magento2, configuration, cron, message-queue

I'm using Magento 2.4.1, and this is my message queue configuration in app/etc/env.php

```
'queue' => [
    'consumers_wait_for_messages' => 0
],
'cron_consumers_runner' => [
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 2,
    'single_thread' => true,
    'consumers-wait-for-messages' => 0,
    'consumers' => [
        'product_action_attribute.update',
        'product_action_attribute.website.update',
        'exportProcessor'
    ]
]
```

I set the max_messages to `2` , I don't know if this is enough or gonna cause any trouble later

Answer (score 1):

I saw this in Magento official devdocs, wondering why you put 2 there

> max_messages - The maximum number of messages each consumer must
> process before terminating (default = 10000). Although we do not
> recommend it, you can use 0 to prevent the consumer from terminating.
> See consumers_wait_for_messages to configure how consumers process
> messages from the message queue.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/mq/manage-message-queues.html

Answer (score 0):

Default = 10000, you can use 0 to prevent the consumer from terminating

Answer (score 0):

cron_consumers_runner' => [
'cron_run' => true,
'max_messages' => 10000,
'consumers' => [

this is my env.php

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/203448)